# Animation applied to shared static resource

Tags: wpf, wpf-animation, wpf-style

I have `RibbonButton` element which uses a `StaticResource` background brush.

Now I am trying to apply animation to the background color of this button, but what happens is all the elements that uses the same `StaticResource` have their background color animated too !!!

How to make this animation applicable only to the `RibbonButton` ?

```
<Ribbon>
    <RibbonTab Header="Ribbon Tab 1">
        <RibbonGroup Header="Ribbon Group 1" Background="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}">
            <RibbonButton x:Name="RibbonButton1" Label="Ribbon Button 1"
                          VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                          Style="{DynamicResource RibbonButton1_RibbonButtonStyle}"
                          Background="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}">
                <RibbonButton.Resources>
                    <Style x:Key="RibbonButton1_RibbonButtonStyle" 
                           TargetType="RibbonButton">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomethingChanged}" Value="true">
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                                            Duration="0:0:0.1" To="Gold" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop">
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                                            Duration="0:0:0.1" To="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </RibbonButton.Resources>
            </RibbonButton>
        </RibbonGroup>
        ....
    </RibbonTab>
</Ribbon>
```

Comment: ""all the elements that share the same StaticResource have their background color animated too"" -- Which are all the elements??\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently when an element uses a `StaticResource`, the same instance of that resource is shared between all the elements that uses it.

So as a solution, I used the `x:Shared="False"` markup attribute on my `StaticResource` and it worked.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Color x:Key="BackgroundColor" A="255" R="250" G="250" B="250" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrush" x:Shared="False" Color="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```